# When I use opencv to extract feature points, ORB is slower than SIFT. Theoretically ORB should be much faster

Tags: performance, opencv, sift, orb

Using the same image, ORB cost 270ms, but SIFT cost 70ms.
This is the code, using default parameters.

```
Mat leftImg = imread("example_data/compare/building0.png");
Mat RightImg = imread("example_data/compare/building1.png");
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

Mat imageDesc1, imageDesc2;
vector<KeyPoint> pots1, pots2;
//Ptr<SIFT> sift = SIFT::create();
//sift->detect(leftImg, pots1);
//sift->detect(RightImg, pots2);
Ptr<ORB> orb = ORB::create();
orb->detect(leftImg, pots1);
orb->detect(RightImg, pots2);
    
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << "pass time:" << (duration<double, milli>(t2 - t1)).count() << endl;
```

Comment: Can you try to exclude both ::create from the time measured parts?